# How to exit this while loop

Tags: python

So basically when a user enters 'n' I need it to stop and not ask to enter either y or n, but I can't seem to make it occur, any help?

```
decider = input('Would you like to play the game? [y/n]? ')

while decider != 'y' :
    if decider == 'n' :
        print('Another time perhaps')
    else :
        print('Please enter either \'y\' or \'n\' ')

    decider = input('Would you like to play the game? [y/n]? ')
```

Also I understand you can use exit or break but in my exercise that is NOT allowed

Comment: Instead of asking at the _end_ of the loop, have you tried asking at the _beginning_? Consider what you'd need to change in your program, if you did that.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I tried putting it at the beginning inside the while loop, but it does the same thing :(

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: @greg-449 Just wanted to delete since I got my solution and didn't want people to keep  helping out, understood! thanks.

Comment: Questions are not just for the person asking but for all the other people who might have a similar problem. So you should not try to delete just because you got an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the user before checking the inputs and before the while loop checks the condition again. Also you need to loop as long as the input is NOT 'n'

```
decider = ''
while decider != 'n' and decide != 'y' :
    decider = input('Would you like to play the game? [y/n]? ')
    if decider == 'n' :
        print('Another time perhaps')
        break
    elif decider == 'y':
        print('Play again!')
        * insert restart code here*
    else :
        print('Please enter either \'y\' or \'n\' ')
```

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to do it, the program would not pass through even if it's a 'y'

Comment: `decider = ' '

while decider != 'y' :
    decider = input('Would you like to play the game? [y/n]? ')

    if decider == 'n' :
        print('Another time perhaps')
    else :
        print('Please enter either \'y\' or \'n\' ')`

I tried this, which is close to working however when I put an 'n' it still asks the question

Comment: Are you trying to exit the loop when the user presses 'y' or rather at 'n'?

Comment: Moray it needs to exit at n, and not ask again when it comes to that, and at 'y' it would just continue to the rest of my program

Comment: Okay, see my changes.

Comment: The thing is Moray I'm trying to do it without a 'break' since it's not allowed for this exercise..

Comment: Ah sorry, then remove the break (and also the != 'y' if it not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it adding other constring to the while ald change it when he inset n. I gave you and example below.

```
import sys

decider = input('Would you like to play the game? [y/n]? ')

while decider != 'y':
    if decider == 'n' :
        print('Another time perhaps')
        sys.exit()
    else :
        print('Please enter either \'y\' or \'n\' ')
        decider = input('Would you like to play the game? [y/n]? ')
```

Well you were rigth I edit the code to not answer the question again

Comment: Hi Andres this seems to work for 'y' and anything that is not 'n', however when 'n' is entered and submitted as a response it still asks the question and on the second attempt it passes through to the second part of my program ...

Comment: Andres this is perfect, it works on solo but my program has two parts: the while loop we are talking about and then another while loop. The thing is I need the loop to not continue to the second part if the user inputs 'n' , any help?

Comment: Okay i finaly understand what you want. i had update the changes now. Now if the user insert an n the program will finish

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
run = True
while run:
    decider = input(•••)
    if decider == "n":
        print(•••)
        run = False
    if decider == "y":
        print(•••)
    else:
        print("Please write either y or n")
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use 'break' for this exercise unfortunately, any other solution?

Comment: Alright, I'll edit the answer to avoid using `break `

Comment: @Danyal Khan check it now, is the answer satisfactory? If it is, please mark it as accepted 

Comment: Nope it still has the same issue, in this case when a user inputs 'y' it will pass through, when a user inputs 'n' it should stop, and when a user inputs anything other than y or n, it should ask them to input either from the two

Comment: @DanyalKhan Okay, check it now